# How do I differentiate an active route with an id (e.g /about#contact) from an active route without an id (e.g /about) in react router's <NavLink />?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an about page (`"/about"`) which includes a contact form. I have linked the form with an id (e.g contact-form). I have a navbar with the following links: 'Home', 'About', 'Contact'.
I have some basic styling for the active route:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Nav() {
  let activeStyle = {
    textDecoration: "underline",
  };

  return(
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/" style={({isActive}) => isActive ? activeStyle : 
               undefined}>
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/about" style={({isActive}) => isActive ? activeStyle : 
               undefined}>
            About
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/about#contact" style={({isActive}) => isActive ? activeStyle : 
               undefined}>
            Contact
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

When I click either 'about' or 'contact' both of them become active but this is not the desired behaviour.
How can I differentiate between the two routes?
I want one route to be active at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly isn't anything supported out-the-box. See this Github [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/5995) regarding "NavLink doesn't get active on hash links".

Response from one of the core maintainers:

> We don't support hash links. This is because of HashRouter and the
> need to support a hash-based history.

To get around this you can add some React state to manage a "hash" and add this to the active matching.

Example:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

function Nav() {
  const [hash, setHash] = React.useState();

  let activeStyle = {
    color: "green",
    textDecoration: "underline"
  };

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            to="/"
            onClick={() => setHash()}
            end
            style={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeStyle : undefined)}
          >
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            to="/about"
            onClick={() => setHash()}
            end
            style={({ isActive }) =>
              isActive && !hash ? activeStyle : undefined
            }
          >
            About
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink
            to="/about#contact"
            onClick={() => setHash("contact")}
            end
            style={({ isActive }) =>
              isActive && hash === "contact" ? activeStyle : undefined
            }
          >
            Contact
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

The gist is to set/clear the `hash` state depending on which link is clicked, and use the `hash` state to match the link's target path string's hash value.

[image: Edit how-do-i-differentiate-an-active-route-with-an-id-e-g-aboutcontact-from-an-a]

[image]
[image]